# CDF V2 Document, No summary info. while using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, jquery-fileupload-rails

Content type not recognizing while uploading files using paperclip + jquery file upload.

Throwing below error "content type discovered from file command: CDF V2 Document, No summary info. See documentation to allow this combination"

fail to upload the same.

Answer (score 1):

We can fix this issue by adding below file in the intializers in rails  -

# config/initializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:content_type_mappings] = {
    :xls => "CDF V2 Document, No summary info"
}
```

This solve my problem, hope this will help you as well.

Thank you.